# Zooming MKMapview to bound annotations makes annotation right on edges of mapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Hi have MKMapView and I make it to zoom depending on the annotations added to mapview, but sometimes I see map zoomed to some level in which annotations fall on the edges and half visible. Below is the code i'm using to set the map region.

MKPolygon *poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:annotationCount];
MKCoordinateRegion region=MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([poly boundingMapRect]);

Please provide some solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your region is too small, have you considered making it bigger?

Your [MKCoordinateRegion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) has a CLLocationCoordinate2D (center) and a MKCoordinateSpan (span). That MKCoordinateSpan has a latitudeDelta (consider this the height) and a longitudeDelta (consider this the width). What you want to do is a make a slightly larger region. So my first guess is

```
region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta * 1.01;
```

Then set your mapview to that region